# How to open file dialog rather than point a file in Marco of MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

Here is the Marco in Word that can produce barcodes, but when I record Marco I have chosen a file (t1.csv), how can I ask users to choose a file?
I have tried some vb code about open file dialog but doesn't work for me

```
Sub To_Bar_Code()
'
' To_Bar_Code Macro
'
'
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:= _
        "C:\Users\jiqi9\Desktop\BC\BarCode\t1.csv", ConfirmConversions:=False, _
        ReadOnly:=False, LinkToSource:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
        PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", WritePasswordDocument:="", _
        WritePasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
        Connection:="", SQLStatement:="", SQLStatement1:="", SubType:= _
        wdMergeSubTypeOther
    With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .SuppressBlankLines = True
        With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
            .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
        End With
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With
    Windows("LabelFinal").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Are we talking vb.net here or vba?  Similar syntax, very different tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub To_Bar_Code()
Dim MMSrc As String
Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
With Application.FileDialog(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogFilePicker)
  .Title = "Select the mailmerge source file"
  .Filters.Add "CSV Files", "*.csv"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
  If .Show = -1 Then
    MMSrc = .SelectedItems(1)
  Else
    MsgBox "No source file selected. Exiting", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
  End If
End With
With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
  .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
  .OpenDataSource Name:=MMSrc, ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=True, _
    LinkToSource:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Revert:=False, _
    Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, Connection:="", SQLStatement:="", _
    SQLStatement1:="", SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeOther
  .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
  .SuppressBlankLines = True
  With .DataSource
    .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
    .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
  End With
  .Execute Pause:=False
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
Windows("LabelFinal").Activate
End Sub
```